# Performing World <--> Device transforms in Direct2D

Tags: gdi+, direct2d, sharpdx

In GDI+, the Graphics object has a TransformPoints function which allows you to specify coordinate transforms for either device to world or world to device. In SharpDX I can take device (independent) co-ordinates and get them translated to my world with Matrix3x2.TransformPoint(...) but how can I go the other way?

Alternatively, what I'm doing is through a series of transforms I end up drawing something on the screen which I only know about in current world co-ordinate but I want to draw a text label on it. I think therefore that I need to drop back to device co-ordinates to draw my text correctly (i.e. set Identity as the transform; drawtext(device x,device y) -- happy days). So if there is a direct solution that doesn't involve TransformPoints then that would make me happy too.

I'm using SharpDX, but I'm happy to translate any c++ answer...

Comment: Not that my linear algebra is good, but I found D2D1InvertMatrix in d2d1.dll and then use that inverted matrix, and that's good. It appears that this isn't exposed in SharpDX??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InvertMatrix() added to SharpDX.

http://code.google.com/p/sharpdx/issues/detail?id=334